# Error al generar "Source: File" php

Tags: php, json

Tengo un problema al momento de generar un reproductor en php con [jwplayer](/questions/tagged/jwplayer), el problema es que el reproductor toma el enlace de mi página más el enlace donde está alojado el video http://miweb.com/https://linkdevideo.12345asdfghjk.mp4

Para generar el video, la página donde se aloja utiliza JSON:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$url = "https://webdondesealojaelvideo.com/getpublinkdownload?code=".$id."";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

$host = $json_data["hosts"][0];
$path = $json_data["path"];
```

y trato de generar el link hacia el video de la siguiente forma:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
sources: [<?php echo '{file:"' . $host . '' . $path . '",label:"low",type: "video/mp4",default: true}'; ?>],
logo : {file: "",
    link: "",
    hide: true,
    },
    abouttext: "",
    aboutlink: ""
  });
</script>
```

y se genera lo siguiente:

```
<video src="/mipágina.com/linkdevideo.com/cBZgcAkZEbjaY7ZZZu6GNq7ZQ5ZZawVZkZSbAWZYXZf7ZqZdVZVkZaXZS7ZWkZ37ZKkZnXZg7ZRVZsVZfDhbZFUWPmCQvU54rv1QEOmXIojUjKIsX/video.mp4"></video>
```

y debería generar lo siguiente:

```
<video src="linkdevideo.com/cBZgcAkZEbjaY7ZZZu6GNq7ZQ5ZZawVZkZSbAWZYXZf7ZqZdVZVkZaXZS7ZWkZ37ZKkZnXZg7ZRVZsVZfDhbZFUWPmCQvU54rv1QEOmXIojUjKIsX/video.mp4"></video>
```

¿Podrían ayudarme a resolverlo?

Comment: No estás usando un schema en el enlace, por lo que el navegador entiende que se trata de un enlace interno. Inténtalo así: `$host = 'http://' . $json_data["hosts"][0];` para forzar un schema http, `$host = 'https://' . $json_data["hosts"][0];` para uno https o `$host = '//' . $json_data["hosts"][0];` para un enlace tipo "schema free" que usará el mismo schema que esté usando el cliente en ese momento.

Comment: @Muriano Gracias! se ha solucionado el problema!, un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: @Muriano Pon la respuesta dada como respuesta en lugar de comentaria para poder 'cerrar' la pregunta!

Comment: Listo @MiquelColl !

Comment: perfecto, ahora @R.13 tiene que aceptarla! un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás usando un schema en el enlace, por lo que el navegador entiende que se trata de un enlace interno.

Inténtalo así:

```
$host = 'http://' . $json_data["hosts"][0];
```

para forzar un schema http,

```
$host = 'https://' . $json_data["hosts"][0];
```

para uno https o

```
$host = '//' . $json_data["hosts"][0];
```

para un enlace tipo "schema free" que usará el mismo schema que esté usando el cliente en ese momento.